what source will explain "en anglaise, en ronde" in Madame Bovary?
Flaubert, Madame Bovary:

Sa maison, du haut en bas, est placardée d'inscriptions écrites en anglaise, en ronde, en moulée:

Lydia Davis translates this as "in running script, in round hand, in block capitals" (page 63; Viking, 2010). Adam Thorpe (page 69; Vintage, 2011) renders "in a sloping hand, in a round hand, in block capitals". So apparently, "en anglaise" means cursive.
Littré explains the term "moulé" and mentions "en ronde":

La moulée, genre d'écriture. La ronde, la moulée.

"Moulé" suggests that something has been cast, such as molten metal poured into a mold or form (French moule).
Thus, handwriting that resembles rectangular blocks of metal type.
But how in the world does one document or explain that "en anglaise" means cursive? Is there a source for this?
And what is the difference between "en anglaise" and "en ronde" handwriting? Does some source elucidate this?
As an American, I understand that Europeans (at least up to the 1980s) learned, as children, a much better handwriting than the typical American. I have seen this in the amazingly clear and fast way that my European professors wrote on chalkboards. This must have been the result of a conscious effort in elementary schools.
Thus, in the context of France, is there a well-documented and vivid distinction between "ronde" and "anglaise"?

Wikipédia l'explique

Académie française: Lettre moulée, Lettre imprimée. Cet écrivain imite parfaitement la lettre moulée. Il se dit, par extension, d’Une lettre dont la forme ressemble à la lettre imprimée. Écrire en lettres moulées.

Larousse explains anglaise:

nom féminin

Caractère d'imprimerie d'origine anglaise, se rapprochant de l'écriture manuscrite.
Écriture cursive, penchée sur la droite.



Larousse also explains ronde: Écriture à jambages courbes, à panse et à boucles presque circulaires.


apparently, "en anglaise" means cursive.

No. Cursive (or joined-up writing), cursive or écriture attachée in French, qualifies any style of calligraphy in which the letters are joined. This type of writing is opposed to print script  (sometimes called block letters), écriture scripte in French, in which the letters are not joined.
L'écriture Anglaise is very close to the English Roundhand, it is slanted to the right. It is cursive writing since the letters are joined up.
L'écriture ronde française is a type of cursive writing in which the letters are round and upright (not slanted).
The following document is taken from a 2013 leaflet designed for school teachers. On the image you can see different historical types of écritures cursives, including the ronde (left, third from top) and the anglaise (bottom right)

I have, very rarely though, seen écriture moulée used to translate the Copperplate script.  The 3rd edition of the Dictionnaire de l'académie (1740) introduced an entry with lettre moulée describing it as a handwriting with letters in the same shape as those found in printed matter. In the present edition it says the term is outdated.  As far as I know the term it is no longer used.  Nowadays Lettre moulée just means a capital letter but I would be surprised a lot of people know what it is in France, apparently they use the term more in Quebec.

I understand that Europeans (at least up to the 1980s) learned, as children, a much better handwriting than the typical American.

There is not a European handwriting. I can tell a French handwriting from a British handwriting at first glance. And both are different from a German handwriting. British and French children are not taught writing in the same way. The leaflet mentioned above shows some handwritings from different countries (pages 15-16).

Re your last comment, I guess the OP means that from an American point of view, there is (or was) a significant difference between the US handwriting way (isolated letters,  écriture scripte) and the various European ways that still commonly use joined cursive letters.
